# Access flask server hosted on Raspberry Pi on Android phone connected via ethernet

Tags: android, networking, raspberry-pi, ip-address, ethernet

I have a raspberry pi which is running a flask server on 0.0.0.0:5000. The raspberry pi is connected to the Android device via a ethernet cable. The android device is running a react-native app which is the frontend.

The problem is that the IP address of the raspberry pi is not fixed and I cannot reliably access the server from the Android phone.

Is there a way to get the raspberry pi IP address on the Android device always?

Raspberry pi IP is not fixed when connected via ethernet to an Android device. Either getting to know the IP address everytime or fixing the IP address to a static IP should work. (I have tried fixing the IP address to static on the raspberry pi but that did not work for me)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.